# Wand can't find ImageMagick shared libraries on Windows

Tags: python, windows, imagemagick, wand

I have installed ImageMagick 6.9.9-34-Q8-x64 following [Wand documentation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows), checked "Install developer headers and libraries", set `MAGICK_HOME` to the right location, but everytime I import anything, Wand complains that it could not find ImageMagick shared libraries:

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows
```

[Full output](https://pastebin.com/ZxD1B2wF)

The interesting part is that when I check paths that Wand tried, (`tried_path` in the [full traceback](https://pastebin.com/ZxD1B2wF)), some of them actually exist, but Wand still fails to use them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is python running x64?

Comment: @emcconville oh, right, I didn't think of that, it's actually 32bit. Installed 32bit ImageMagick and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @emcconville can you please post your comment as an answer so I could mark it is accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Double check the python interpreter is running `x84_64`, or the CDLL will not be able to load `x64` dynamic libraries.

Either reinstall ImageMagick, or Python, but ensure that the runtime/dynamic libraries match architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I uninstalled the last ImageMagick version, with an [older version](ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.10-10-Q16-x64-dll.exe) I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

there are x86 and x64 versions to be choose. use the one fits your machine. further, using a little old version might come easier.